# javascript onchange event calling a function with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am having problems with the following code:
I have n numbers of select box, whose id are differentiated by the values that the variables ModName and level take:

```
container.innerHTML = '<form id="listToolForm_'+ModName+level+'"><select id="listToolSelect_'+ModName+level+'" onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex,'+ModName'+, level)"><option value="0">---</option></select></form>';
```

The select box is then populated by values taken from a database (this part is not really relevant here). With each form, there is a hidden input with id= `idArg'+ModName+'_lev'+level`, that will store the index selected by the user, using `onChange` and the function selValue(x):
Here is the function `selValue(index, ModName, level)`:

```
function selValue(index, ModName, level){
    document.getElementById("idArg"+ModName+"_lev"+level).value = index;
}
```

I tried the script setting `var ModName = "SL"`, and `var level = 0`. I get an error: 'SL is not defined'. Another test that worked is by replacing the function that fires up `onChange`:

```
onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex)"
```

and

```
function selValue(index){
    var level = 0;
    var ModName = "SL";
    document.getElementById("idArg"+ModName+"_lev"+level).value = index;
}
```

So if the function fired up onChange has one argument, the code works, but does not when using several arguments. I suspect it's because of the line:

```
onChange = "selValue(this.selectedIndex,'+ModName'+, level)"
```

I tried:

```
onChange="'+window["selValue"](this.selectedIndex, ModName, level)+'"
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (I assumed `'+ModName'+` was a typo in the question and not in the actual code):
`onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex, ' + ModName + ', level)"`
causes JavaScript to substitute `ModName` with its value, which results in the actual HTML being:
`onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex, SL, level)"`
When handling the onChange event, the JavaScript engine "thinks" `SL` is a variable (hence the error), but you actually want it to be a string (if I understood well).

To turn `SL` into a string, you should surround it with single quotes. To do that, you will need the `\'` escape sequence, since you're already using nested quotes. Simply replace:
`onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex, ' + ModName + ', level)"`
with:
`onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex, \'' + ModName + '\', level)"`

Also, didn't you mean:
`onChange="selValue(this.selectedIndex, \'' + ModName + '\', ' + level + ')"`
?